# Set TableViewController as root view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

Im doing a app who require the seller to fill a form with additional data after the login, only if is the data has not sended.

so if the data from the api is not nil the user is loging to the normal Tab Bar Controller

and if the data from the api is nil the user must be login to the form, but apparently I can't do that with a table view controller

```
if tipoUsuario == "ROLE_VENDEDOR" {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let perfilVendedor = datos["perfilVendedor"].string

        if perfilVendedor == nil {                        
            let paginaInicio = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"DatosVendedorTableViewController") as! UITableViewController

            let wnd = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
            var options = UIWindow.TransitionOptions()
            options.direction = .toBottom
            options.duration = 0.6
            options.style = .easeOut
            wnd?.setRootViewController(paginaInicio, options: options)
            //this is not working

        } else {
            let paginaInicio = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"PaginaDeInicioVendedorViewController") as! UITabBarController

            let wnd = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
            var options = UIWindow.TransitionOptions()
            options.direction = .toBottom
            options.duration = 0.6
            options.style = .easeOut
            wnd?.setRootViewController(paginaInicio, options: options)
            //this is  working fine
        }
   }
}
```

[this is my main story board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZD0Z.png)

This is my first app and im looking for the best way to implement it 
Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any error.. or its just opening the TabViewController?

Comment: if the `else` part is working correctly, it's obvious the `perfilVendedor` is never `nil`.  Have you tried setting a breakpoint? Either that, or you have not explained your problem correctly.

Comment: @Aditya this is the error:  Failed to set (keyPath) user defined inspected property on (UIVisualEffectView): [<UIVisualEffectView 0x161e17d10> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key keyPath.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Storyboard (<UIStoryboard: 0x1d0078900>) doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'DatosVendedorTableViewController''
***

Comment: The error states that your main Storyboard does not contain  "DatosVendedorTableViewController" .. Please once again check that your TableViewController has the same identifier.

Comment: @Aditya yes actually that's was the problem  thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Storyboard Identifier for your UITableViewController in Storyboard.

Like

[image]

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.values.mainStoryboard, bundle: Bundle.main) // StoryBoard name
let initialSceneVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Storyboard Id") as! YourUITableViewController

self.application.windows.first?.rootViewController = initialSceneVC  //Assign Root View
```

Comment: oh men you save me, I have missed the last letter in the Storyboard ID ‍♂️ thank you!

Comment: Its Okay my friend